# Attach a new virtual field after save using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my schema...

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
});
```

This is my model...

```
const PersonModel = model('Persons', personSchema, 'persons');
```

This is my person object

```
const person = new PersonModel({
  firstName: 'Rick',
  lastName: 'Biruel'
});
```

When I save my object...

```
const result = await person.save();
```

...I wish my person object with a third virtual field called 'fullName' like this:

```
console.warn('result');
// result = {
//   firstName: 'Rick',
//   lastName: 'Biruel',
//   fullName: 'Rick Biruel'
// };
```

To achieve this result, I tried this to no avail....

```
personSchema.post('save', async function () {
  this.fullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
});
```

P.S. No error occurs, but the third field 'fullName' doesn't exist in my person object. *The `fullName` field must not persist on database!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [VirtualType](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/virtualtype.html#virtualtype_VirtualType), and you can also find an [example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/virtualtype.html#virtualtype_VirtualType-set) that is very similar to your problem in Mongoose official documentation.

Comment: Can you show me an example using VirtualType inside the .post('save') middleware? I tried it without success.

Comment: VirtualType works now, I just added this object in my Schema: { toJSON: { virtuals: true } }. Thanks so much @Alex Dumitru